# Memcache/Memcached confusion, windows compatibility and php7 compatibility

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I am learning how to apply the caching system to my website (because my I/O is always hitting the limit). Then I searched to how solve it, and the answer is Memcache/Memcached.

Here are my questions:

1. How to identify what type of caching system (Memcache/Memcached) the web host is using?

   (Connected to question 1) If I know what the web host is using, I am be able to download and make a test on my localhost before applying it to the website.
2. Where to download Memcache/Memcached extension that is compatible to PHP7 and windows 7? (I need to make sure that the codes runs before applying it to the production)

   I saw Memcache/Memcached codes in PHP.net and it's differ from Memcached.org.
3. Which one I will choose? PHP.net or Memcached.org?

   Note: The web host using (Linux, Apache), mine is (Windows 7, XAMPP(Apache))

ALERT: More questions will be added if the questions are being answered and if I made a progress.

Comment: The memcache(d) on PHP is an extension for PHP and acts as client, the server Memcache(d) is still needed.

Comment: @Terminus they are using Ubuntu

Comment: @CharlotteDunois You can answer my questions anytime, thank you!